# Still impossible to view a solution's commit history in Visual Studio 2017 when using git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Right-click on a solution in Visual Studio 2017 and select 'View History...'. You only get changes to the solution itself. I want to see the commit history of everything it contains. Or barring that, the entire repository.

I found answers to this question that are many years old, telling you to use the command line, and I'm finding it hard to believe that this is still the answer.

As of January 2019, is there still no way to view the entire commit history of a solution within Visual Studio?

Comment: Ugh I thought I researched the question diligently before posting. Yep, that's the answer.